# Help finding the common factor of $q^{n-1}-p$ and $kq-p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

let $p,q$ be 2 non-zero coprime integers,$n\in\mathbb{Z}>1$ and $k$ any integer. For what $k$ do $q^{n-1}-p$ and $kq-p$ have a common factor?

So far, I have been able to come up only with the obvious solution $k=q^{n-2}$ by brute force. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

From the way the problem is stated I understand that for given $p,q,n$ you want to find the $k$' which work.

**Hint**  If $d \neq 1$ is a divisor of $q^{n-1}-p$ then $d$ is a common factor if and only if

$$kq \equiv p \pmod{d} \,.$$

Now, using the coprime condition you can prove that $p$ and $d$ must also be coprime, therefore $p$ is invertible $\mod{d}$.

This shows that 
$$k \equiv q^{-1}p \pmod{d}$$
for some divisor $d \neq 1$ of $q^{n-1}-p$.

Comment: Did you mean $kq\equiv p\pmod d$?

Comment: @NumThcurious Yes, fixed.

Comment: @ N.S. but $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Doesn't it imply $q^{-1}p$ is a rational number?

Comment: @NumThcurious $q^{-1}$ is the inverse modulo $d$, thus an integer...

Comment: I think that's assuming $q|d$ and $q|p$...Please correct me if  I am wrong

Comment: I was thinking $k\equiv q^{n-2} \pmod d$

Comment: @NumThcurious To have an inverse you only need the number to be relatively prime with the modular arithmetic.

Comment: How would that change if I was trying to divide $q^{n-1}-p$ by $kq-p$?

Comment: @NumThcurious What do you mean divide? If you divide you get a rational number. Modular inverse is not really division, even if the idea comes from there....

Comment: $(kq-p)|(q^{n-1}-p)$

Comment: it does not have to be rational as long as $k=q^{n-2}$.

Comment: @NumThcurious And what if $k \neq q^{n-2}$? You have to find ALL $k$....

Comment: so there are no solutions?

Comment: @NumThcurious I proved in my answer that for each $d$ which divides $q^{n-1}-p$ there are infinitely many solutions, and described all. Note that some of them appear for multiple $d$...